# nvd3 forceX to display months

Tags: nvd3.js

I need your help,

I can't display months in the x-axis line
In the X Axis i would like to display months(['Jan','Fev','Mars','Avr','Mai','Juin','Juil','Aout','Sept','Oct','Nov','Dec']) but It display 0 to 12.

This is my code:

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
        var chart = nv.models.lineChart();

        chart.xAxis
                .axisLabel('Mois')
                .tickFormat(d3.format(',`enter code here`r'));

        chart.yAxis
                .axisLabel('Pourcentage')
                ;
        chart.forceY([0, 100]);
        d3.select('#chart svg')
                .datum(getPercent())
                .transition().duration(500)
                .call(chart);

        nv.utils.windowResize(function() {
            d3.select('#chart svg').call(chart)
        });

        return chart;
    });

function getPercent() {
        var habitation = [],
                voiture = [],
                seminaire = [],
                months = [Jan','Fev','Mars','Avr','Mai','Juin','Juil','Aout','Sept','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
        $.each(months,function(i,element){
            habitation.push({x: i, y: Math.ceil((54 / 12) * i)});
            voiture.push({x: i, y: Math.ceil((18 / 12) * i)});
            seminaire.push({x: i, y: Math.ceil((10 / 12) * i)});
        });

        return [
            {
                values: habitation,
                key: 'Echéance habitation payée',
                color: '#2E3FD3'
            },
            {
                values: voiture,
                key: 'Echéance voiture payée',
                color: '#3CD32E'
            },
            {
                values: seminaire,
                key: 'Séminaire remboursé',
                color: '#C40B18'
            }
        ];
    }
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072721/formating-the-date-in-nvd3-js) should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code :

```
chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function (d) {
    // %b - abbreviated month name.
    return d3.time.format('%b')(new Date(d))
});
```

If you need more information on farmatting date/time read [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072721/formating-the-date-in-nvd3-js)

To show all the months you can use :   `chart.xAxis.tickValues(['Jan','Fev','Mars','Avr','Mai','Juin','Juil','Aout','Sept','Oct','Nov','Dec'])`

A little more reading info on axis [`here`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-ticks)

---

**`UPDATE`**

By looking at your [`code`](http://jsfiddle.net/Othmen/bbSn2/)  I think the problem is with your data. You do not seem to be passing the date. If you print `index` in you `tickFormat` you will get a set of random number from 0-12, so it will not work with the d3 Date function.

I have made a few changes to your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/shabeer90/27mGK/) . For the date to work correctly make sure send a date, currently I have used a unix timestamp.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your help,
I solved the problem with this code:
months = ['0','Jan','Fev','Mars','Avr','Mai','Juin','Juil','Aout','Sept','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
//I would like that the x-Axix line start with 0.

chart.xAxis
      .axisLabel('Mois')
      .tickFormat(function(index) {
            return months[index];
      });

But my problem now that I can't show all months, It just display
(Fev, Avr,Juin, Aout, Oct, Dc).

Any Idea ?

Comment: @user3248550 - Its better to use the inbuilt feature to get the date month. Its showing only selected months baybe cuz it only contains data for that particular dates. I have updated my answer to show all the months value.

Comment: this is my code on jsfiddle...It doesn't work Or I can't understand your suggestion well.

Can you give me a complete script. This is my one.
[Personal example](http://jsfiddle.net/Othmen/bbSn2/).Thanks