# How to customize format of Y value from seconds to min/sec in NVD3.js

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm trying to draw the chart with data in following format:

```
[
 {'label':'0', 'seconds':1094},
 {'label':'1', 'seconds':1096},
 {'label':'2', 'seconds':1112},
 ...
]
```

and the result looks like this:
[image]

It looks good and the question is:
**How to customize the format of displaying Y value to this?**:

[image]

**UPDATE:**
The code building the chart

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart = nv.models.multiBarHorizontalChart()
        .x(function(d) { return d.label })
        .y(function(d) { return d.value })
        .margin({top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 20})
        .showValues(true)           //Show bar value next to each bar.
        .tooltips(false)             //Show tooltips on hover.
        .transitionDuration(350)
        .showControls(true);        //Allow user to switch between "Grouped" and "Stacked" mode.

    chart.yAxis
        .tickFormat(d3.format(',.0f'));    

    d3.select('#chart1 svg')
        .datum(jsonData)
        .call(chart);

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

    return chart;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this

```
 chart.yAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
    // %M - minute as a decimal number [00,59].
    // %L - milliseconds as a decimal number [000, 999].
    return d3.time.format('%M%L')(new Date(d))
});
```

**UPDATE :**

```
// Line Not Tested but valueFormat should do the trick
chart.valueFormat(d3.time.format('%M%L'));
```

Take a look at [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072721/formating-the-date-in-nvd3-js) if you need more time formatting options.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've tried. The API `tickFormat` only modify the text displaying on the axis but not displaying next to the bar.

Comment: @jcjason - have a look at the updated code and check the `valueFormat` option.