# reformat large csv dataset using d3 for nvd3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have a csv dataset with multiple mentions of the same item (ie conflict name - england IRA, israel palestine etc), and values of dates and number_of_casualties for each specified date.

I want to express this using nvd3 stacked area chart:
http://nvd3.org/examples/stackedArea.html

the format that it uses in the example is:

```
key : "category a"
values: [ [ date , amount ] , [ date , amount ] ....]
```

here's some fo the actual code in the example:

```
   {
            "key" : "Energy" ,
            "values" : [ [ 1138683600000 , 1.544303464167] , [ 1141102800000 , 1.4387289432421] , [ 1143781200000 , 0] , [ 1146369600000 , 0] , [ 1149048000000 , 0] , [ 1151640000000 , 1.328626801128] , [ 1154318400000 , 1.2874050802627] , [ 1156996800000 , 1.0872743105593] , [ 1159588800000 , 0.96042562635813] , [ 1162270800000 , 0.93139372870616] , [ 1164862800000 , 0.94432167305385] , [ 1167541200000 , 1.277750166208] , [ 1170219600000 , 1.2204893886811] , [ 1172638800000 , 1.207489123122] , [ 1175313600000 , 1.2490651414113] , [ 1177905600000 , 1.2593129913052] , [ 1180584000000 , 1.373329808388] , [ 1183176000000 , 0] , [ 1185854400000 , 0] , [ 1188532800000 , 0] , [ 1191124800000 , 0] , [ 1193803200000 , 0] , [ 1196398800000 , 0] , [ 1199077200000 , 0] , [ 1201755600000 , 0] , [ 1204261200000 , 0] , [ 1206936000000 , 0] , [ 1209528000000 , 0] , [ 1212206400000 , 0] , [ 1214798400000 , 0] , [ 1217476800000 , 0] , [ 1220155200000 , 0] , [ 1222747200000 , 1.4516108933695] , [ 1225425600000 , 1.1856025268225] , [ 1228021200000 , 1.3430470355439] , [ 1230699600000 , 2.2752595354509] , [ 1233378000000 , 2.4031560010523] , [ 1235797200000 , 2.0822430731926] , [ 1238472000000 , 1.5640902826938] , [ 1241064000000 , 1.5812873972356] , [ 1243742400000 , 1.9462448548894] , [ 1246334400000 , 2.9464870223957] , [ 1249012800000 , 3.0744699383222] , [ 1251691200000 , 2.9422304628446] , [ 1254283200000 , 2.7503075599999] , [ 1256961600000 , 2.6506701800427] , [ 1259557200000 , 2.8005425319977] , [ 1262235600000 , 2.6816184971185] , [ 1264914000000 , 2.681206271327] , [ 1267333200000 , 2.8195488011259] , [ 1270008000000 , 0] , [ 1272600000000 , 0] , [ 1275278400000 , 0] , [ 1277870400000 , 1.0687057346382] , [ 1280548800000 , 1.2539400544134] , [ 1283227200000 , 1.1862969445955] , [ 1285819200000 , 0] , [ 1288497600000 , 0] , [ 1291093200000 , 0] , [ 1293771600000 , 0] , [ 1296450000000 , 1.941972859484] , [ 1298869200000 , 2.1142247697552] , [ 1301544000000 , 2.3788590206824] , [ 1304136000000 , 2.5337302877545] , [ 1306814400000 , 2.3163370395199] , [ 1309406400000 , 2.0645451843195] , [ 1312084800000 , 2.1004446672411] , [ 1314763200000 , 3.6301875804303] , [ 1317355200000 , 2.454204664652] , [ 1320033600000 , 2.196082370894] , [ 1322629200000 , 2.3358418255202] , [ 1325307600000 , 0] , [ 1327986000000 , 0] , [ 1330491600000 , 0] , [ 1333166400000 , 0.39001201038526] , [ 1335758400000 , 0.30945472725559] , [ 1338436800000 , 0.31062439305591]]
        }
```

two questions pls:

1. How to I aggregate and format my csv data to that format?
2. What time format is that?

Comment: not sure what you wanted to group by (eg conflict > date or date > conflict, or something else) . I would check out d3.nest() and come back if you have questions with that

Answer (score 0):

Answers to your questions,

1. To aggregate, slice and dice large datasets for d3 charts have a look at [**Crossfilter**](http://square.github.io/crossfilter/).

> Crossfilter is a JavaScript library for exploring large multivariate
>   datasets in the browser. Crossfilter supports extremely fast (<30ms)
>   interaction with coordinated views, even with datasets containing a
>   million or more records;

Here's an example taken from [Crossfilter Tutorial](http://blog.rusty.io/2012/09/17/crossfilter-tutorial/) by Rusty.io :

```
var livingThings = crossfilter([
  // Fact data.
  { name: “Rusty”,  type: “human”, legs: 2 },
  { name: “Alex”,   type: “human”, legs: 2 },
  { name: “Lassie”, type: “dog”,   legs: 4 },
  { name: “Spot”,   type: “dog”,   legs: 4 },
  { name: “Polly”,  type: “bird”,  legs: 2 },
  { name: “Fiona”,  type: “plant”, legs: 0 }
]);

// How many living things are in my house?
var n = livingThings.groupAll().reduceCount().value();
console.log(“There are ” + n + “ living things in my house.”) // 6

// How many total legs are in my house?
var legs = livingThings.groupAll().reduceSum(function(fact) { return fact.legs; }).value()
console.log(“There are ” + legs + “ legs in my house.”) // 14
```

You can find a few tutorials on how to get started here :

- [Crossfilter Tutorial](http://blog.rusty.io/2012/09/17/crossfilter-tutorial/) by Rusty.io
- [Getting to know Crossfilter](http://animateddata.co.uk/articles/crossfilter/) by Peter Cook

---

2. The date **`1138683600000`** is currently Unix Time Stamp.

You can define how you want the date to be displayed in your when passed into your chart. Check this answer on StackOverflow on how to [Format the date in nvd3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072721/formatting-the-date-in-nvd3-js)

Here is an example :

```
chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
    // Will Return the date, as "%m/%d/%Y"(08/06/13)
    return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d))
});
```

Hope it helps.