# NVD3 - line chart NaN on safari using latest versions

Tags: jquery, d3.js, nvd3.js

using NVD3 as a line chart all of my data is being inserted into one vertical line (as opposed to be across the horizontal) and when I hover the line I get 0NaN repeated. this only happens using safari

here is the java:

```
function drawChart(div, att_speed, data) {
  nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
    .interpolate("cardinal")
    .forceY([0,att_speed])
    ;
    // Convert the date passed as a STRING into a DATE object
    chart.x(function(d) { 
      return new Date(d.x); 
    });
    chart.xAxis.axisLabel('Time (m)');
    chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
      return d3.time.format('%H:%M')(new Date(d));
    });
    chart.yAxis
      .axisLabel("Speed (mb)") //Set Y-Axis attributes.
      .tickFormat(d3.format(".0f")) //Set Y-Axis label formatting.
    ;
    d3.select("#" + div + " svg") //Select the document's <svg> element
      .datum(data) 
      .transition().duration(500).call(chart); //Define transition and pass the d3.selection to our lineChart.

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

    return chart; 
  });        
}
datalink_one = [
        {
            values: [{"x": "2018-06-19 14:21:22", "y": "80"}, {"x": "2018-06-19 14:24:02", "y": "89"}, {"x": "2018-06-19 14:25:10", "y": "127"}, {"x": "2018-06-19 14:28:04", "y": "91"}, {"x": "2018-06-19 14:30:11", "y": "92"}, {"x": "2018-06-19 14:31:21", "y": "80"}, {"x": "2018-06-19 14:34:03", "y": "131"}, {"x": "2018-06-19 14:35:28", "y": "98"}, {"x": "2018-06-19 14:37:11", "y": "86"}, {"x": "2018-06-19 14:39:02", "y": "111"}, {"x": "2018-06-19 14:42:03", "y": "95"}, {"x": "2018-06-19 14:43:04", "y": "165"}, {"x": "2018-06-19 14:45:11", "y": "89"}, {"x": "2018-06-19 14:47:11", "y": "133"}, {"x": "2018-06-19 14:49:16", "y": "134"}, {"x": "2018-06-19 14:52:05", "y": "157"}, {"x": "2018-06-19 14:54:13", "y": "66"}, {"x": "2018-06-19 14:55:09", "y": "95"}, {"x": "2018-06-19 14:58:02", "y": "112"}, {"x": "2018-06-19 14:59:09", "y": "98"}],
            key: "Download",
            color: "#337ab7",
            area: true   
        },
        {
            values: [{"x": "2018-06-19 14:21:22", "y": "17"}, {"x": "2018-06-19 14:24:02", "y": "49"}, {"x": "2018-06-19 14:25:10", "y": "44"}, {"x": "2018-06-19 14:28:04", "y": "57"}, {"x": "2018-06-19 14:30:11", "y": "18"}, {"x": "2018-06-19 14:31:21", "y": "14"}, {"x": "2018-06-19 14:34:03", "y": "20"}, {"x": "2018-06-19 14:35:28", "y": "24"}, {"x": "2018-06-19 14:37:11", "y": "19"}, {"x": "2018-06-19 14:39:02", "y": "29"}, {"x": "2018-06-19 14:42:03", "y": "12"}, {"x": "2018-06-19 14:43:04", "y": "13"}, {"x": "2018-06-19 14:45:11", "y": "22"}, {"x": "2018-06-19 14:47:11", "y": "14"}, {"x": "2018-06-19 14:49:16", "y": "29"}, {"x": "2018-06-19 14:52:05", "y": "14"}, {"x": "2018-06-19 14:54:13", "y": "11"}, {"x": "2018-06-19 14:55:09", "y": "29"}, {"x": "2018-06-19 14:58:02", "y": "15"}, {"x": "2018-06-19 14:59:09", "y": "25"}],
            key: "Upload",
            color: "#5cb85c",
            area: true   
        }
    ]
drawChart('one-speed-chart', 500.0, datalink_one)
```

here is a fiddle (which will fail in safari)

https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/279009/

here is a screeshot
[image: screenshot of issue]

Comment: Can you add your code in a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), so its easy for someone to help you.

Comment: hi Ive added a fiddle, unfortunately I cannot even get the NanNan anymore though, im not sure what ive done but nvd3 is currently not rendering

Comment: on the left hand menu in the fiddle there is a "Resources" section where you can add the [CDN](https://cdnjs.com/) of the libraries you are using. Make sure to update it with the same library versions you are using, D3, NVD3 and the CSS

Comment: ive done this I think, thanks

Comment: @shabeer90 any ideas?

Comment: Try to avoid having numbers in your HTML TAG ID. The id TAG must start with letter, rename your TAG ID from `2-speed-chart` to maybe `two-speed-chart`. [Here's a technical explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have finally found the answer, for safari, the date time format needs to be as follows in your json

```
%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S
```

This question I found lead me to the answer [Safari Javascript Date() NaN Issue (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21883699/safari-javascript-date-nan-issue-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss)

Answer (score 0):

A few things I noticed when playing with your code.

In parts of your dataset for `key: 'Upload'` you have got the the values for `'x'` inside single quotes, would be good to keep it consistent in your dataset. I normally DO NOT use the single quotes for `x`.

The reason you are getting **0NaN** is because you are passing the date as a STRING and NOT a DATE object.

So here is what I added to your code :

```
var chart = nv.models.lineChart(); //Create instance of nvd3 lineChart  

// Convert the date passed as a STRING into a DATE object
chart.x(function(d) {     
  return new Date(d.x);
});
```

Here is a working version of your code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/shabeer90/j0a8qbe1/).

I would suggest formatting your dates in the X Axis to avoid them overlapping with each other. You can find more about time [formatting using d3.js here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072721/formatting-the-date-in-nvd3-js)

---

**UPDATED** working version with your code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/shabeer90/nxtkrufj/)

To fix the **NaN** issue on Safari browser you can format the time accordingly

```
  chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')(new Date(d));
  });
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Ive copy pasted your code near identically into my code and for some reason I am just getting blank and in debug I get the error "the string did not match the expected pattern" line 4312 in d3.js. ive updated the question to show my code

Comment: @AlexW your `X` values in the dataset has to be the full date timestamp so it can be converted into a date object in the `chart.x()` function. And then in the `tickFormat()` function you can choose how you want it rendered in the chart.

Comment: @AlexW you have two options. 1) Leave it as `x: '2018-06-07 14:59:11'` or 2) pass the date as a unix timestamp `x: '1528383551'`. For now I suggest going with Option 1. Have you managed to look at the demo I shared in my answer?

Comment: yes I have copied against your demo and am still getting the error SyntaxError: The string did not match the expected pattern. ive changed the date format back also as per option 1

Comment: Can you update your question with your latest code and the exact error code

Comment: ok, changing the IDs to words has fixed the loading, now im back to the original issue where all the values appear on one vertical line and say NaN, even though I have used your code to specify dates

Comment: @AlexW strange, your code works perfectly for me. Have  you got the correct [d3](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js) and [NVD3](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.5/nv.d3.js) files?

Comment: when I load this fiddle, I see all the results in one vertical like and NaN on them all, do you not see this when you load the fiddle?

Comment: @AlexW no I don't, here is the [latest fiddle with your code](https://jsfiddle.net/shabeer90/nxtkrufj/)

Comment: OK, its safari, when I load it in chrome I can see the chart but not in safari. do I need to add anything extra for safari, as I know it works, as when I load the samples from the nvd3 website they work in safari, just my charts do not... ive added the jsfiddle image to the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173471/discussion-between-shabeer90-and-alexw).